# How can I change the font of the VS2010 Source Control Explorer window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The Visual Studio 2010 Source Control Explorer window displays quite nicely on my Windows 7 box.

The only problem is, it's quite hard for me to see the difference between the bold and regular sub-items and I don't want to filter everything "non-bold".

Is there a way to change the font for this window?

Comment: To open the window, go to: `View -> Other Windows -> Source Control Explorer`. It only works properly if Team Foundation Server is your selected source control plug-in.

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg, I can open the window just fine, but don't know how to customize the font used in the window.

Comment: I just added that for people who might be looking for that window to find a solution. Cause I had a hard time finding it myself, as I use AnkhSVN for source control (and, thus, was unable to help).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found that if you open the Tools/Options Window -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors 
Environment Font, controls the generic fonts in Visual Studio Including Source Control Explorer

[image]

Comment: You are clearly "saving the day, one day at a time" ;-)